# Trouble setting styles for nested elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having trouble setting up nested styles in WPF.  I don't know if I'm doing things the 'right way' - but I'll describe what I'm attempting to do and provide some code.

I'm working with Kinect and am using a ContentControl to represent a Kinect object in my ViewModel.  I declare it as such:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Kinect}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SkeletonTemplate}" />
```

I then set up the SkeletonTemplate as such:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SkeletonTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding HandLeft}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource JointTemplate}"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding HandRight}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource JointTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Lastly, I set up a JointTemplate as such:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="JointTemplate">
    <Ellipse Fill="Red" Margin="0,0,620,460">
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Path=Position.X}" Y="{Binding Path=Position.Y}" />
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>
</DataTemplate>
```

Everything is all hunky dory except I'd really like to be able to set a Style at highest level that allows me to style the nested elements.  For example, I want to be able to do this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Kinect}" Style="{DynamicResource ShrunkBlueSkeleton}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SkeletonTemplate}" />
```

And immediately apply a set of rules to the nested elements.  Make the ellipses Blue, apply a ValueConverter to the ContentControls in the SkeletonTemplate to scale them to a smaller part of the screen, etc.

I'm having a bitch of a time getting it working, and I'm not sure if I've even set up everything up in the 'right' way to this point.

Certainly I could re-declare a ton of different ContentTemplates that style in all the different ways I need to, but that is much more obviously bad style.

Any pros out there that can lend a hand?

I could paste the Style attempts I've made thus far, but I'm rather convinced they won't help the discussion.

Comment: Cannot answer your question but try using Expression blend for styling.... It will help a lot.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The root feature that you are missing is that Style's setters works on Properties and not on Path (a la Binding) - which I believe is what you would like to have.

There are technical reasons for Microsoft did that: Style works on specific styles and not on compound elements. Similar styling frameworks (most notably: CSS) also support "setters" just for one element (although, arguably, the select is much superior).

Comment: That's strange - so it's not possible to create a template of sorts for a particular compound element?

I mean, the ultimate end goal I'm shooting for here is taking this Kinect object with properties for each joint that each have their own respective way of being rendered, and being capable of effectively dropping it into the XAML anywhere and easily setting a user-defined style on it.

Is there an alternative way I could set things up to accomplish that?

Comment: @Reno - You can create custom control (that is, your own object derived from Control or ContentControl, or even ItemsControl would make sense in your case for all the joins), and then create a ControlTemplate (not a DataTemplate), and use {TemplateBinding} for various properties you want to expose. Take a look at this tutorial: http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html